# Bash: How to split a command line into a list of arguments verbatim?

Tags: string, bash

For example, when given a command line:

```
ls "aaa bbb"
```

I'd like to have a list of arguments:

```
args[0]='ls'
args[1]='"aaa bbb"'
```

Is this possible with Bash and common UNIX utilities (sed, awk, xargs, etc.)?

Please note that the arguments must be verbatim. Below is NOT a correct answer:

```
args[0]='ls'
args[1]='aaa bbb'
```

Comment: What you are going to do with arguments capturing? Not clear, kindly do let us know more details what you want to achieve here?

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible because the shell always performs **quote removal** before it executes a command. In consequence, commands will never see (be able to access) the removed quotes.

This sounds like an XY-problem. Why do you think you need the original quoting? What is your actual problem?

Comment: This is really more of a comment than an answer.

Comment: @glennjackman It's a direct answer to the asked question: "Is this possible with Bash and common UNIX utilities?" and it explains why. It's a proof of a negative.

Comment: To rewrite the command line before further processing. I think getting the original string would be better than re-quoting, if it's possible.

Comment: @Cyker The original quoting would be only useful to a shell (other programs just deal with their unquoted args), but in a shell you can use `"$@"` to pass the positional parameters as-is as a set, or just use `"$1"` etc. Can you provide us with a real-life situation where you need the original quotes? I haven't come across one in 30 years and do shell programming for a living.

Comment: @thatotherguy, cheeky!